# Android Voice call: Put phone number as a parameter in TwIML params map

Tags: android, twilio, voip

I've some issues related to a making VOIP call from Android using Twilio Voice SDK.

I created my own endpoint for making calls and I'm using the hardcoded phone number in the server code to make a call to this specified (hardcoded) phone number (which I also verified from Twilio Voice console). I'm using the callerID number which I put from the Android code (also verified from Twilio Voice console).
Is it possible to make calls by specifying also phone number from Android code?

```java
final HashMap<String, String> twiMLParams = new HashMap<>();
twiMLParams.put("to", callerId);

// make call
Voice.call(this, accessToken, twiMLParams, callListener);
```

Maybe there will be something like this (which I've found from my google searches, but couldn't find any documentation about this):

```java
twiMLParams.put("to", callerId + "," + number);
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the URL below and see if that addresses your question.

**voice-quickstart-android/Docs/new-features-3.0.md**

https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/3.x/Docs/new-features-3.0.md#custom-parameters

"You can now send parameters from the caller to the callee when you make a call. The key/value data is sent from the Voice SDK to your TwiML Server Application, and passed into TwiML to reach the callee."